# Link .a file into .so file

Tags: c++

I have created `libdemodyn.so` file from `LDemo.cpp` file that `LDemo.cpp` file have linking with `demolink.a` file and another `symbolD.o` file. But when I am consuming `libdemodyn.so` file it gives "undefined reference" error to the functions which are defined in `demolink.a` file not for the functions in `LDemo.cpp`. Is creation of `.so` not done properly or liking to .cpp?

Using this I have created the libdemodyn.so:

`g++ -fPIC -c LDemo.cpp -l ./symbolD.o -I ./ -L ./ -ldemolink -lpthread -ldl -o libdemodyn.o`

`g++ -shared -o libdemodyn.so libdemodyn.o`

And I am consuming it as:

`g++ TestLIb.cpp -I ./ -L ./ -ldemodyn -lpthread -ldl -o test`

Comment: You probably need to add the `-ldemolink` to the link step, where you're actually making the .so.

Comment: @Rob K : i have tried this , g++ -g -O0 -shared -o libdemodyn.so libdemolink.a libdemodyn.o symboD.o   But still, it gives same error.